# MySQL Join by groups

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to match two tables based on score and year to find which ids belong together. I made up the following example:

Table a:

```
  id | score | year
  1      0     2000
  1      1     2001
  1      2     2002
```

Table b:

```
id_match | score_match | year
  10           0         2000
  10           1         2001
  10           2         2002
  20           0         2000
  20           0         2001
  20           2         2002
```

id_match = 10 has the same scores as id = 1for all year whereas for id_match = 20 it is different in year = 2001. I want to match only the ids which have exactly the same scoring in all years.

The output table simply could look as follows:

```
id | id_match
1      10
```

I guess it is a relatively simple query. I was thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id_match
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
  ON a.score = b.score
  AND a.year = b.year
GROUP BY a.id, b.id_match;
```

However, I would like to have a match only if scores of id and id_match are equal for all years.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT b.id_match
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON a.year = b.year
GROUP BY b.id_match
HAVING SUM(a.score <> b.score_match) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select a.id, b.id_match from tableA a, tableB b
  where a.score = b.score
    and a.year = b.year
    and b.id_match not in (select b.id_match from tableB b, tableA a
                             where b.score != a.score
                               and b.year = a.year
                            group by b.id_match)
 group by a.id, b.id_match;
```